# Wrong permutation output

Tags: javascript, permutation

I'm having problem with this code. I want to print all permutations, but I get the wrong output.

```javascript
function Swap (array,index1,index2)
{
    var temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;
}
function Permutation(ArrayNum , StartIndex)
{       
    if(StartIndex == ArrayNum.length-1)
    {
        console.log(ArrayNum);          
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = StartIndex; i< ArrayNum.length; i++)
        {
            Swap(ArrayNum,StartIndex,i);
            Permutation(ArrayNum,StartIndex + 1);
            Swap(ArrayNum,StartIndex,i);
        }               
    }               
}
```

For example, for three numbers, I get this output, which isn't the full list of permutations.

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: From where did you get the algorithm? Try it on paper.

Comment: This algorithm is everywhere on the net it is the backtracking algorithm and i think it is correct but the output is not

Comment: If the algorithm is correct, then the problem would have to be in how you call the function or how you print the result, but you don't show either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `i` variable is global, where it should be local. You can see the error, if you set strict mode with `"use strict";`

```
        for(i = StartIndex; i< ArrayNum.length; i++)
              ^

ReferenceError: i is not defined
```

Without the error, it would go through one loop only.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i declare variable i inside a loop and i think it is a local ..... anyway is there any edit to my code that fix this problem

Comment: Thank you very much paiv by adding var before i the code worked properly but i dont understand why this problem occurred because i didnt have any variable i in all of my code.

again thank you very much 
im a rookie developer and i appreciate you for your help.